# How can I find the perpendicular to a 2D vector?

Tags: vector, linear-algebra

I'm making a top down game where the player moves forwards towards the position of the mouse cursor. As part of the player's movement code, I need to determine a vector that is perpendicular to the player's current facing vector (to implement strafing behavior).

How can I compute the perpendicular vector of a given 2D vector?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I always forget how to do this when I need it so I wrote a couple of extension methods.

```
    public static Vector2 PerpendicularClockwise(this Vector2 vector2)
    {
        return new Vector2(vector2.Y, -vector2.X);
    }

    public static Vector2 PerpendicularCounterClockwise(this Vector2 vector2)
    {
        return new Vector2(-vector2.Y, vector2.X);
    }
```

And a unit test

```
    [Test]
    public void Vector2_Perpendicular_Test()
    {
        var a = new Vector2(5, -10);
        var b = a.PerpendicularClockwise();
        var c = a.PerpendicularCounterClockwise();

        Assert.AreEqual(new Vector2(-10, -5), b);
        Assert.AreEqual(new Vector2(10, 5), c);
    }
```

[image: perpendicular lines]

Comment: If you have a vector (5,-10) then it'll be in quadrant 4, right? If you then rotate it clockwise, won't it be in quadrant 3 i.e. both components negative? Have you got your functions mixed up?

Comment: They are the other way around. PerpendicularCounterClockwise should return (10,5) and PerpendicularClockwise should return (-10,-5).

Comment: Oh my.. this was wrong for 3 years. My apologies to anyone who used it. I've now fixed the answer and drew a diagram to prove that it makes sense this time. Thanks to @opetroch and PeteUK for pointing this out. Sorry it took so long to correct it.

Answer (score 55):

To get the 2D vector perpendicular to another 2D vector simply swap the `X` and `Y` components, negating the new `Y` component. So `{ x, y }` becomes `{ y, -x }`.

Comment: Note that there are two possibilities, and this one will get you the left-hand perpendicular vector. (-y|x) is the right-hand side vector.

Comment: You should negate the y axis to have a CCW rotation by traditional convention.

Comment: @TravisG I think you've got the left and right mixed up? (-y, x) is the left hand perpendicular vector and (y, -x) is the RHS from my calculations.

Answer (score 8):

If [image: (ax, ay)], then a-perp obtained by a counterclockwise rotation by 90 degrees, i.e., [image: (-ay, ax)]

See this [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerpendicularVector.html) :)